# After animation in CSS the object changes position a little bit

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a login page, and I want an animation of the input swiping in from below. This is the code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  animation: swipein .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes swipein {
  from {
    top: 30%
  }
  to {
    top: 20%
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

But after the animation ends, the input moves a little bit to the right, as you can see in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ev1ewbc7/3/) jsfiddle link. Why does that happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `height` is 80%, and the starting `top` is 30%. Together they are higher than the body height, and this creates a scroll bar on the right. After the animation ends, the `top` is 20%, and the scrollbar disappears. When the scrollbar disappear form jumps right.

If you remove the form's height, you won't get the height overflow and the scrollbar.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  animation: swipein .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes swipein {
  from{top:30%}
  to{top:20%}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

the change is caused by the scrollbar, you need to hide it to fix the problem

add `overflow: hidden;` to body

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  animation: swipein .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes swipein {
  from {
    top: 30%
  }
  to {
    top: 20%
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's due to `top: 30%` and `height: 80%` adding up to a  height which extends 100%. This results in a vertical scroll bar which takes up some horizontal space, but disappears after the animation, therefore the horizontal skip.

If you use `height: 70%`, it works without a scrollbar.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  animation: swipein .5s ;
}

@keyframes swipein {
  from {
    top: 30%
  }
  to {
    top: 20%
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```